# CSS container min-height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get my container to fill 100% height as some pages have limited information on them.

I have tried setting footer positions, content min heights etc...

Best I've managed is setting content to absolute and it then goes more than 100% and hides the footer.  I tried a auto margin minus the height of footer but no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Client Check</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <a href="../index.php"><img src="../images/logo-header.jpg" /></a>
    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="navtext">How it works</a>
        <a href="#" class="navtext">About us</a>
        <a href="#" class="navtext">Help</a>
        <a href="#" class="navtext">Services</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlogin">Log in</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="search">
        <h2>Check a Client</h2>
        <form method="post">
            <h3>Client info</h3>
            <label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lname" />
            <label>House Number/Name:</label><input type="text" name="address" />
            <label>Postcode:</label><input type="text" name="post" />
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <img src="../images/logo-header.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a> | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></p>
    <p>&copy; 2015 Client Check.  All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

#content{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#about{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#about h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#F48C6B; 
}

#about p{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #878786;
}

#about span{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F48C6B;
}

#about button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #57BB89;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px #4AA478;
}

#about button:hover{
    color: #F48C6B;
}

#how{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    text-align: center;
}

#how h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#F48C6B; 
}

#checkclient{
    width: 280px;
    height: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px #B5B2B2;
}

#reportclient{
    width: 280px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px #B5B2B2;
}

#how button{
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #57BB89;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

#how button:hover{
    color: #F48C6B;
}

#how p{
    color: #858889;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em; 
}

#how button img{
    max-width: 20px;
    max-height: 20px
}

#search{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #EFEDE7;
    text-align: center;
}

#search h2{
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    color:#F48C6B; 
}

#search form{
    width: 450px;
    height: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px #B5B2B2;
}

#search form h3{
    color: #57BB89;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#search form label{
    width: 200px;
    color: #C9C8C8;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

#search form input[type=text]{
    width: 170px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #C9C8C8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#search form input[type=submit]{
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #57BB89;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #5C5D5D;
}

#footer img{
    max-width: 180px;
    max-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#footer p{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

#footer a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F48C6B;
}

#footer a:visited{
    color: #F48C6B;
}

#footer a:hover{
    color: #00BB89;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the height dynamically with the `calc` propery.

Simply set the height to be 100% the height of the viewport with `100vh` and then subtract the height of the footer (130px) and header (130px) = 260px.

```
#content{
   width: 100%;
   height: calc(100vh - 260px);
   min-height: 500px;
}
```

To then prevent it from going too small, you can add a `min-height` property of your liking.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yy174bpo/)

Comment: Because it's effectively setting `position: fixed;`, which is fine on this page but on others where there is plenty of content, the footer is stuck at browser bottom not page.  Also, that doesn't help fill the container space, just creates white space between container end and footer start.

Comment: The footer is now always at the bottom. If there is alot of content it goes at the bottom of the page. If there is little content, it still goes bottom. And no overlap. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No, that's not what I put in the question?  You have managed two methods of fixing the footer, but the question asks for the container to 100% height if content does not fit browser window...

Comment: It sounded like you wanted help with the footer. But ok, are you okay with using javascript to solve this?

Comment: I am hoping for a CSS fix I'm afraid.

Comment: That got it, thank you!  Jut got to figure auto centre vertical haha :P

Comment: No problem! and here you go - auto centre middle :) http://jsfiddle.net/yy174bpo/1/

Comment: Thanks :)  Was trying to figure out why it wouldnt go with blocks haha.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That very nearly does it, puts a long scroll on the page, about 500px.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply the below CSS.

```
#header{
    height: 15vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content{
    height: 70vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer{
    height: 15vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I guess this is what you are trying to get. Depending on your needs, you'll have to change the height of Header, Content and Footer.

Comment: Same issue as another answer here, it works but adds roughly 500px v scroll on the page

Comment: I've changed the code. Test it, you might be looking for that kinda solution! Though, your question is confusing.